# SQL SELECT Statment

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make a `SELECT` but I can´t test it on SQL management studio because it's always giving me errors.

I can´t find the error, any help is appreciated, thanks !

```
SELECT [Order].CustomOrderNumber, [Order].OrderTotal, [Order].OrderDiscount, [DiscountUsageHistory].DiscountID, [DiscountUsageHistory].OrderID, [Discount].ID, [Discount].Name 
FROM (([Order] , [Discount] , [DiscountUsageHistory] 
INNER JOIN [DiscountUsageHistory] ON [Order].CustomOrderNumber = [DiscountUsageHistory].OrderID) 
INNER JOIN [Discount] ON [DiscountUsageHistory].DiscountID = [Discount].ID)  
WHERE OrderDiscount > 0
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Which are you using?

Comment: SQL Server I guess

Comment: Also, come join 2018. 1989 was almost 30 years ago now: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: you can write what error ? @user6505433

Comment: I´m newbie in coding SQL so I don´t know the bad habits sorry

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','. @KillerQueen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your relations are correct -

You had multiple tables linked to `from`.

The inner join makes those relations for you.

```
    SELECT [Order].CustomOrderNumber, [Order].OrderTotal, [Order].OrderDiscount, [DiscountUsageHistory].DiscountID, [DiscountUsageHistory].OrderID, [Discount].ID, [Discount].Name 
    FROM [Order] 
    INNER JOIN [DiscountUsageHistory] ON [Order].CustomOrderNumber = [DiscountUsageHistory].OrderID
    INNER JOIN [Discount] ON [DiscountUsageHistory].DiscountID = [Discount].ID 
    WHERE [Order].OrderDiscount > 0
```

Comment: Always happy to help a fellow developer out.

Answer (score 3):

Your query has a strange mixture of implicit joins and explicit joins.
You should never use implicit joins, ever.

A correct query structure would be something like this:

```
SELECT [Order].CustomOrderNumber, 
       [Order].OrderTotal, 
       [Order].OrderDiscount, 
       [DiscountUsageHistory].DiscountID, 
       [DiscountUsageHistory].OrderID, 
       [Discount].ID, 
       [Discount].Name 
FROM [Order] 
INNER JOIN [DiscountUsageHistory] ON [Order].CustomOrderNumber = [DiscountUsageHistory].OrderID
INNER JOIN [Discount] ON [DiscountUsageHistory].DiscountID = [Discount].ID 
WHERE OrderDiscount > 0
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
    ORD.CustomOrderNumber, 
    ORD.OrderTotal, 
    ORD.OrderDiscount,
    DISUH.DiscountID,
    DISUH.OrderID,
    DIS.ID, 
    DIS.[Name]

FROM 
    [Order] AS ORD  
INNER JOIN 
    [DiscountUsageHistory] AS DISHU ON ORD.CustomOrderNumber = DISHU.OrderID
INNER JOIN 
    [Discount]  AS DIS ON DISHU.DiscountID = DIS.ID 
WHERE ORD.OrderDiscount > 0
```